# How to see which file are in use in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a question how can I see which file are in use in linux. To be honest this OS is not the normal version of linux it is very crippled so for example there is no command like "lsof". I found command "strace" but this is no what I looking for. I hear that I can list this file with hacking kernel?

I want to see which file are in use because on this machine is a little free space and I want to delete file which are no in use when the program is running.

I'm sorry for my weak english.

Comment: You might want to (cross-) compile the `lsof` utility for your target Linux system, at least during the debugging phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the open files by process by walking the [/proc virtual filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)

Every process running has an entry in /proc/PID. There's a directory in each process directory called 'fd', that represents the processes currently opened [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). These appear as links to the actual resources.

e.g. on a VM I have running

```
root@wvm:/proc/1213/fd# pidof dhclient
1213
root@wvm:/proc/1213/fd# cd /proc/1213/fd
root@wvm:/proc/1213/fd# ls -l
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 20 -> socket:[4687]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 21 -> socket:[4688]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 3 -> /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 4 -> socket:[4694]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  8 09:11 5 -> socket:[4698]
root@wvm:/proc/1213/fd#
```

Looking at the kernel process information for 'dhclient' - I find its pid, and then look in the fd subdirectory for this process id. It has a small set of open descriptors - stdin, stdout and stderr ( 0,1,2 ) have all been attached to /dev/null , there's four sockets open, but file descriptor 3 is attached to a data file `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases`

So you could duplicate the functionality of lsof using shell tools to walk /proc and filter out the file names from these links.

Comment: Based on this answer, to get all files currently open, you can use this command: `sudo ls -l /proc/*/fd/ | grep '.-> /' | grep -v '.-> /dev' | sed 's/^.*-> //' | sort -u`

Comment: It's very useful but this is no what I looking for :) 

I try to describe what I want one more time :

I want to know what file was open when I try to use command,  for example "grep". Command from tivn show me what file/procces is use in this moment , but I want to see what file was using to perform command.

Comment: /proc/{pid}/maps seems to contains the information you need. e.g. `cat /proc/{pid}/maps | grep '\/' | sed 's-^.*  /-/-' | sort -u`

Comment: It's better but what about program's that don't execute system function name 'map'. They won't be see in /proc/{pid}/maps

Comment: @Adrianeo OK, that's more of a job for strace. Filter the output for open and look for filenames -e.g. strace grep foo /var/log/messages 2>&1 | grep open | perl -lane '/"(.+)".*/ and print $1'

Comment: @tivn /proc/pid/maps is just for memory mapped files, which is just a specific subset of currently open file descriptors

Comment: Unfortunately this OS don't have to command "perl" 
-sh: perl: command not found

On normal linux you're command works fine. 

There is the question is there any possibility to enable profile usage of files on this OS.

Comment: Now I see that without this " | perl -lane '/"(.+)".*/ and print $1' " this command work fine too.

Comment: @Adrianeo - perl is just a convenient shortcut for formatting. Command works without perl fine, also you could use awk or sed or cut or anything else similar

Comment: Now I see that without this " | perl -lane '/"(.+)".*/ and print $1' " this command work fine too.

But now I have one more question. Did there is any opportunity to see which file are in use but when the process are started automatic (for example which file , libraries  etc. read "init" when system start.) I found something name "fanotify" anybody heard  about this?

Comment: @Adrianeo inotify / fanotify can get you events based on filesystem changes. A better way might be to use DTrace ( hard to get on linux ) , or systemtap probes to log file open events somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use "top" command? if so then this should show you the list of all the top OS utilizing operations running on linux. You can do

```
ps -ef|grep <process_no>
```

this would give the details of it. Either can stop that process or kill it using

```
kill -9 <process no>
```

Comment: can you please specify what linux based OS are you using and which version?

Comment: Linux version 3.4.91-WR5.0.1.24_standard   it is WindRiver

Answer (score 0):

Use the [lsof command](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/) to list all open files by process.

Comment: This is why I shouldn't read questions this late! I see the OP clearly stated lsof wasn't available.  That said I'll leave this answer up with the link just in case it's useful to any other visitors.

Comment: One last comment: getting lsof on WindRiver might be simply a matter of `sudo yum install lsof`